How to change Peer signature type to RSA
I have problem where after upgrading from Docker Debian (debian:stretch-slim) to Docker Ubuntu (FROM ubuntu:focal) and from Apache2 to Nginx.
Old self signed cert for production uses different Peer Signature Type than Ubuntu stretch.
How to I change Peer signature type to RSA?
what is openssl settings to force use RSA not RSA-PSS?
Wiht openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myserver
Old server displays:
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits

SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384


New server displays
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits

Added ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1; to nginx to get Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits had.
How to I change Peer signature type to RSA? Can't find almost anything about it online.
nginx conf
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    client_max_body_size 100m;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server2.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server2.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

    ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1; # Without this Ubuntu server displays Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits

    
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
        proxy_pass http://puma;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_error_log;   

}


These are the internal workings of the TLS protocol, and the newer version may be using TLS ver. 1.3 which uses RSA-PSS. As long as it succeeds, why does the signature type matter?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk One client have trouble accessing from old Java client which have been working without touching over 10 years.

Then you need to include full error details from that incident.

@MysteriousNothing Java has great backwards compatibility and the TLS implementation is in the base library (JSSE). Have you tried upgrading the JRE and see if it runs? Because there are other security reasons to keep the JRE up to date, obviously. NB it may be best to recompile as the byte code has received updates as well.

/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
Add to top of conf
openssl_conf = openssl_init

Add to bottom of conf

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
SignatureAlgorithms = RSA+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA256

restart nginx/apache
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
